# Most efficient way to find the last digit of a^b

Tags: number-theory

I am a python newbie. I am looking to compute `(a ** b) % 10` in the most efficient way possible (i.e. simplifying the power part). I have found one way to do this: `((a % 10) ** b) % 10`. My question is, are there more efficient ways to do this? This problem is an extension of a CodeFights task. The original problem accepted `(a ** b) % 10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Since the numbers *mod 10* form a [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)), you can compute the residue *mod 10* at every intermediate value without influencing the result.
- There is a `O(log b)` step algorithm called [Square-and-multiply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) that can drastically speed up your computations.

  The basic idea is that for even `b`, we can just square the argument
  and divide the exponent by 2 without changing the result.
  For odd `b`, we extract one power of `a` (or our current argument) and proceed like in the even case (squaring and halving).

So putting this together, if you implement the Square-and-multiply algorithm and compute the residue *mod 10* after every step, you will have a nice and efficient way to compute your last digit.

Comment: Thanks! I also found another method. This method takes all the residues of `a` mod 10 and then finds a pattern. I used a dictionary to do the pattern mapping. I approved your solution since it is a bit more efficient than my new solution.

Answer (score 1):

- **step 1:** Take the inputs ***a*** and ***b*** as character **string**
- **step 2:**

  - convert only the last character of ***a*** into **integer** and store in a variable say ***m***.
  - convert only the last two character of ***b*** into **integer** and store in a variable say ***n***.
    If ***b*** is a single character, then convert this character only.
- **step 3:** find x.   `if n % 4 == 0:
                    x = 4 
                else:
                    x = n % 4`
- **step 4:** `last_digit = (m ** x) % 10`

**Short Explanation:** 
If you list out the initial expansions of a power, you will find a pattern.
So we can reduce ***a*** and ***b*** to ***m*** and ***x*** respectively.
Because it is just about the last digit.

you can visit: [this site for the better explanation to find out last digit of a^b](https://brilliant.org/wiki/finding-the-last-digit-of-a-power/)